# In which namespace Application.OnLaunched is located?

Tags: c#, wpf, hockeyapp

I am trying to add HockeyApp to my WPF app, but cannot find Application.OnLaunched ?
Any thought appreciated thanks!

https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/hockeyapp-for-applications-on-windows#crash-reporting

> For platforms other than UWP, you need to add the following line of
>   code at the end of the OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) Method
>   (in App.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that KB page is incorrect. There's no `OnLaunched` method in WPF `Application` class. The nearest equivalent will be [`OnStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note, that Silverlight `Application` differs from WPF one - you need to handle [`Startup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup(v=vs.110).aspx) event, because there's no virtual `OnStartup` method there.

Comment: Adding HockeyClient.Current.Configure("App_ID") in `OnStartup` worked! Thanks Dennis saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

it is located in the system.windows.application